# Rows.Count with dropdown list

Tags: c#, .net, drop-down-menu

Using .net 4 and c# I'm trying to get data from database into GridView and display the number of rows returned. I also have a dropdown list used as ControlParameters in SqlDataSource to filter results.

This works fine on initial page load, but when I select something from the dropdown the results are filtered, but rows count doesn't change. When I select another item from the dropdown, the rows count gets updated but with the number correct for the previous value.

```
        <h5> Showing <asp:Label ID="WOs_count" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label> Work Orders.</h5>  

        <asp:DropDownList 
            ID="DropDownList1" 
            runat="server" 
            AutoPostBack="True">
            <asp:ListItem Value="%">All requests</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="BBTeam">BB Team</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

The Select statement:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource 
    ID="WorkList" 
    runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT TASKS.WOID AS wo_id, Tasks.Completed AS 'Completed Date', Tasks.Respons AS 'Technician', FROM Tasks WHERE (Tasks.Completed>=DATEADD(day,-60,GETDATE())OR Tasks.Completed IS NULL)  AND (Tasks.Respons LIKE @Respons)  ">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter name="Respons" ControlID="DropDownList1" PropertyName="SelectedValue"/>
    </SelectParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Then in the code behind I have this:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        WOs_count.Text = WO_list.Rows.Count.ToString();
    }
```

I'm completely new to .net so wouldn't be surprised if I miss something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is that the Page_Load event is firing before the grid is re-binding to the data, which is why the count is always one postback behind.

You could try updating the count in a later Page event, like `OnPreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)` or updating the count in the DataBound event on your Grid View...

Add this to your ASPX :

```
 <asp:GridView ID="WO_list" runat="server" OnDataBound="WO_list_DataBound" ... />
```

and then add this to the Code Behind (C#):

```
protected void WO_list_DataBound(EventArgs e){ WOs_count.Text = WO_list.Rows.Count.ToString(); }
```

Give this a try and let me know if either/both work.

Comment: Thanks Matt, but still no luck. The first one doesn't change anything; the second gives me an error: '`Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.bb_systems_counter_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'WO_list_DataBound' and no extension method 'WO_list_DataBound' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.bb_systems_counter_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`'

Comment: I see.  I believe I had a typo.  Sorry about that, but it's fixed now.  The casing on the event was wrong...  So you tried overriding OnPreRender and the two pieces of code to bind that event?

Comment: Could you post more of your ASPX?  At least the asp:GridView opening server tag?  Also, try changing the access modifier on your WO_list_DataBound from private to protected, as my edit shows.

Comment: Hi Matt, sorry for long time without response. I managed to get this to work. The second method you gave me works after slight modification of code behind: `protected void WO_list_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)`.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

This should fix it for you.

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        WOs_count.Text = WO_list.Rows.Count.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Why would you put it on SelectedIndexChanged?

Comment: Yep, I thought about it as well, and tried already, but no, this doesn't fix. I also tried running count on Page.IsPostBack, but the same result.